# Addtobackstack is not working properly in android

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

When I am adding `HomeFragment` in `addtoBackStack` and visit another fragment `SecondFragment` then,came back again on `HomeFragment` then layout not able to restore its data.This is what i have done in below code,inflate the layout once.So that when i came back layout does not inflate again

```
    Please help me
```

.

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_display, container,
                    false);
        } else {
        }
```

Comment: This is not the problem with backstack, you have to save the data manually

Comment: Show me your code.

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        if (rootView == null) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_display, container,
                    false);        } else {
            }

Comment: update it in question please. will helps other as well

Comment: Updated, you can check

Comment: show us your code that you add  fragment did you use   transaction.replace   
or  transaction.add method ?

Comment: Yes i have used

Comment: post code for how you are replacing or adding fragment to container

Comment: if (fragment != null) {
            String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (title.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                toolbar_title.setText(title);
            }